DaisyUI / TailwindCSS button group with breakpoint
I would like to join some buttons like so:
<div class="join">
  <button class="btn join-item">Action 0</button>
  <button class="btn join-item">Action 1</button>
  <button class="btn join-item">Action 2</button>
</div>



However a user might set to have any number of actions (usually not more than 7) and so I would like the button group to "wrap" or break the line.
I considered putting them into a grid, using flex, max width but I don't seem to get it to work.
The ideal solution has maybe 3 columns and if there are 5 items, the rounding of the buttons occur not just the outside, but the inside border as well, so at the intersection of items 2,3, and 5.
I did not find any similar problems, workarounds would also work if I'm missing some UI best practice.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how to ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.
